# Slack - Incoming Webhook, issue with &amp;

Tags: php

the Slack docs say that we need to replace the characters &, < and > with & and so one.

I have a pretty simple approach and I do the following curl request:

```
$data = "payload=" . json_encode(array(
                "channel" => "#{$room}",
                "text" => $message,
                "icon_emoji" => $icon,
                "username" => 'My Bot'
            ));

$ch = curl_init($webhookUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Now I send the following $data to Slack, with `&amp;` in the text:

```
payload={"channel":"#test","text":"This is a test &amp; looking not good","icon_emoji":":monkey_face:","username":"My Bot"}
Result "invalid_payload"
```

Here I get a response "invalid_payload".

When I remove the & from the text, everything is fine:

```
payload={"channel":"#test","text":"This is a test looking good","icon_emoji":":monkey_face:","username":"My Bot"}
Result "ok"
```

Does anybody know what I need to change, that the text with & will also be valid?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to

> urlencode()

the payload.

Check out this link:
https://api.slack.com/docs/message-formatting